# An object with the name already exist in the database while its not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a table named `dbo.ProductValue` and I think I have deleted it. Now when I want to create a table with the name `ProductValue` and it shows me the error:

> An object with the name dbo.ProductValue already exist in the database

But in fact it is not exist or at least I can not see it. I have the `sa` access.

**Tries:**

- I close and reopened the window
- I restarted the `MSSQLSERVER` service

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: what says `drop table dbo.ProductValue`?

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev It says: Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'dbo.ProductValue' because 'dbo.ProductValue' is a constraint. Use ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT.

Comment: @HamidReza So try what SQL Server is suggesting in the error message and tell us if it works

Comment: this name being used as constraint in other table, check where it hide on other table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's obviously not a table, but it does exist in the DB, so let's look for it:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects AS S
WHERE name = 'ProductValue'
```

Note downd the `parent_obj` (for example 12345). And now see what the parent object is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects AS S WHERE id = 12345
```

According to your comments, it's a constraint in a table. The second query will give you the table,and now you can use SSMS (or a DDL sentence) to get rid of that object so that you can use that name for a new table.

[Docs for the sys.objects table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx).

Comment: Great answer. I had a table name Product and another one named Value that have a relation named ProductValue. This ProductValue is not related to the ProductValue table and its all a relation name but after renaming that the problem is solved! Thanks.